# Why print(x, digits=20) does not correctly truncate/round x?

Tags: r, rounding

I expect the result of the command below to be `0.54742763380700947` (truncating) or `0.54742763380700948` (rounding).

```
> print(0.54742763380700947685, digits=20)
[1] 0.54742763380700943
```

Why is it `0.54742763380700943`? Where this "`3`" at the end comes from?

Comment: Strange, where I paste it, I get 0.54742763380700942832

Does it depend on the system (32-bit/64 bit)?

Comment: (I'm using 64 bit.)

Comment: This is interesting too: typing `options(scipen=999); 0.54742763380700947685*10^20` I get `54742763380700946432` on a 64bit Windows7 PC.